# SQL Table Syntax

Tags: sql, join

I have not used SQL in a while but need to create some reports.  I'm trying to learn again but not sure of how to find the info.  In the script below what are the p1 & p2 called?  Are these just columns in the payroll table?

```
select distinct p1.* from PAYROLL p1, PAYROLL p2
where
      p1.EFFORTLINEITEMID = p2.EFFORTLINEITEMID
      and p1.PAYROLLAMOUNT = p2.PAYROLLAMOUNT
      and convert(varchar,p1.PAYROLLSTARTDATE, 101)=convert(varchar,p2.PAYROLLSTARTDATE, 101)
      and p1.PAYROLLID <> p2.PAYROLLID
      and p1.INSTITUTIONID ='######'
      and p1.PERIODSTARTDATE ='9/1/12'
      order by PERIODSTARTDATE desc,CERTIFIERID, PAYROLLAMOUNT
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago)

Comment: Also: what **concrete** database is this for? SQL is just the query language - used by many database products. Is this for Oracle? IBM DB2? MySQL? Postgres? SQL Server? Something else entirely? Please update your tags accordingly!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 3):

> In the script below what are the p1 & p2 called?

These are the alias names of your tables. You have created two alias names `p1` and `p2` for your table `PAYROLL`.

For more information or details check [ALIAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28SQL%29)

**On a side note:-**

As marc_s correctly pointed you should try to avoid the habit of joining tables using comma. Instead try using **JOINS**. Check **[Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)** for reasons.